# Notepad++, user defined language hilite disappeared

Tags: notepad++

I used "User-defined dialogue" in notepad++ to get syntax highlight for my macro language. It took me about one hour to get it perfect. But today the language just disappeared from the notepad++. Any idea why this happens? How to make sure my user-defined language will not disappear again?

[image: The menu I used to get to the user-defined dialog window]

[image: dialog is empty, but I filled it few days before]

Comment: Has Notepad++ been updated in this time?

Comment: nope, 6.1.4 for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell *why* you lost your User Defined Language and *how* to not loose it again because it simply should never ever be lost by itself!

I've searched the list of [open bugs](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/search/?q=!status%3Aclosed+%26%26+text%3Adefined+language) and the only related issue is [#2074](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/2074/), but you mentioned that you haven't updated N++ so I guess this not the case (by the way it would be a good idea to update it to the latest version 6.5).

The User Defined Language is saved in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\userDefineLang.xml`. You could check if the file exists and is not empty, maybe the UDL is still there but the application can't read the file for some reason. In the future you could backup this xml for extra security.